# ¿Como cambiar letra y números de forma aleatoria?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con nombres de `productos` deportivos.

```
IdProducto  |    Nombre    |  Cantidad  |  Precio/unidad
====================================================
     1        ASICS4             20         59.99
     2        ADIDAS             10         85.00
     3        KALENJI 58         17         29.99
     4        VAN RISEL 5        9          129.99
    ...       ...                ...        ...
```

Necesito hacer una modificación en la columna de `nombre` que cambie las letras por por otra letra aleatoria y los números por cualquier número aleatorio con una sentencia `update`.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Hola, es una petición muy extraña, ¿estas pensando hacer vandalismo en alguna base de datos o cual es la razón?

Comment: @the-breaker No, simplemente quiero probar con mi base de datos para poder hacerla más segura

Comment: Pero seria una que el cliente lo solicita (un grupo de row's o 1) o toda la tabla de golpe?

Comment: @Srsole sería toda la columna `nombre` de golpe

Comment: ufff para eso solo se me ocurre hacerlo con cursores, por que tienes que recorrer todo el vachar y evaluar que es si numero o letra y depende de eso generar una letra nueva o un numero nuevo, y despues hacer el update, y eso para toda la tabla. Tiene curro.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando como base el código de la rutina [`shuffle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11860364/6836377), no es complejo adaptarla a tus requerimientos: randomizar letras y números por separado.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS rnd_str;

CREATE FUNCTION rnd_str(
    v_chars TEXT
)
RETURNS TEXT
NOT DETERMINISTIC -- multiple RAND()'s
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_retval         TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE u                INT UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE v_rep_str_upper  VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE v_rep_str_lower  VARCHAR(35);
    DECLARE v_rep_num        VARCHAR(11);
    DECLARE c_char           VARBINARY(1);
    DECLARE c_new_char       VARCHAR(1);

    SET v_rep_str_upper = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    SET v_rep_str_lower = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz';
    SET v_rep_num       = '1234567890';
    SET u               = 1;
    
    WHILE u <= LENGTH(v_chars)
    DO
      SET c_char = MID(v_chars, u, 1);
      
      SET c_new_char = CASE WHEN INSTR(v_rep_str_upper, c_char) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(v_rep_str_upper, RAND()*27+1, 1)
                            WHEN INSTR(v_rep_str_lower, c_char) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(v_rep_str_lower, RAND()*27+1, 1)
                            WHEN INSTR(v_rep_num, c_char) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(v_rep_num, RAND()*10+1, 1)
                            ELSE c_char
                          END;

      SET v_retval = CONCAT(v_retval, c_new_char);
      SET u = u + 1;
      
    END WHILE;

    RETURN v_retval;
END;
```

Detalles:

- Es una función que recibe una cadena y la retorna "randomizada"
- El truco, es manejar cadenas de substitución para las letras y los números por separado  y generar un numero random con `RND()` para extraer un caracter de las mismas, aplicando luego este criterio, a cada caracter de la cadena de entrada
- Es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas
- Atención: no soporta caracteres multibyte, es decir codificaciones del tipo unicode, pero no es difícil adaptar eventualmente la lógica.

Ejemplo de uso :

```
SELECT nombre, rnd_str(nombre)
    FROM TuTabla;
```

Ver [**fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bbbf2b84f60841835b1f246c1c450d68)

Comment: Hola! en el `fiddle` tu código va perfecto, tal y como yo quería, pero a la hora de pegarlo en `Workbench` me da error después del `BEGIN` en los `DECLARE`

Comment: @Maginon, que error te dá? que versión de mysql? Revisa la sintaxis para crear funciones desde el workbench por si eventualmente hay alguna diferencia.